# Correct representation for Venn diagram

Tags: probability

Me and my colleague are debating about which one is the correct way to represent a venn diagram. Please let us know which one of the three is the correct answer.

[image]

A. [image]

B. [image]

C. [image]

Update: I pasted the same question in chat gpt and it gave me the following response, so answer should be B according to chatgpt and me.

[image]

Comment: Which do you think personally think is correct and why?

Comment: I think B is correct but my colleague says C. because the number inside Mammals should be total mammals, whether or not they are birds

Comment: In A and B I would read the $80$ in the diagrams to mean the number of mammals which are not birds.

Comment: Someone at the zoo is very much confused. There are no animals that are both mammals and birds. If there could be, then C accurately represents the described scenario.

Comment: but is that how venn diagrams work? the number 150 in square should mean total in the universal set, not the total excluding the mammals and birds. similarly, the number of mammals should be written in the set representing mammals whether or not they are birds

Comment: there is a reason why A(union)B=A+B-A(intersection)B

Comment: The number within the rectangle, but not within the ellipses, represents the number of animals that are neither mammals nor birds. Each number in the diagram represents a *distinct subset* of the whole. The total number of objects represented is the sum of all numbers in the diagram.

Comment: I updated the question, and chatgpt says the same as I am saying :)

Comment: I just want to know what's going on, because this is what I learned 15 years ago. If things have changed overtime. This video also says the same, so I am still confused about what the right way is. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqDVrXq_eh0

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8VHzEFVmLA At about 1:30 into the video, he explains how the diagram is filled.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that there are no mammal-birds in existence (as pointed out by *Daniel* in the comments), I don't see any reason for debate here. $C$ is the correct representation.

One of the different reasons why $A$ can't be correct is - the universal set (zoo) is shown to have $210$ animals as opposed to $150$ (stated clearly in the question).

Similarly, B is also incorrect. It shows $310$ animals in the zoo.

$C$ has no such problems. Every number checks out.

Comment: so this person (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqDVrXq_eh0) and chatgpt are wrong?

Comment: @VipinVerma anyone who claims otherwise is wrong.